# Rounding timestamp to the nearest 30 seconds

Tags: kdb

My table is as follows:

```
t: ([]dt: 2021.10.25T09:30:28 2021.10.25T09:30:32;price:9.99 10.00)
```

I wish to round the timestamp to the nearest 30sec mark.
I tried using xbar like so:

```
update roundedDt: 30 xbar dt.second from t
```

However it seems to have floored the results.
The desired result should be 09:30:30 for both rows.

How can one round to the nearest 30 second mark?

Answer (score 3):

Jonathon's answer is the most flexible for modifying the rounding for not just seconds specifically but an alternative simple solution for just seconds would be to offset by 15:

```
q)update roundedDt:30 xbar 15+dt.second from t
dt                      price roundedDt
---------------------------------------
2021.10.25T09:30:28.000 9.99  09:30:30
2021.10.25T09:30:32.000 10    09:30:30
```

Edit: If you want the full dateTime rounded, I would convert it to timestamp as easy to work with and adjust my offset/xbar to match.

```
q)update roundedDt:30000000000 xbar 15000000000 + `timestamp$dt from t
dt                      price roundedDt
-----------------------------------------------------------
2021.10.25T09:30:28.000 9.99  2021.10.25D09:30:30.000000000
2021.10.25T09:30:32.000 10    2021.10.25D09:30:30.000000000
2020.10.25T23:59:59.000 9.99  2020.10.26D00:00:00.000000000
2020.10.26T00:00:01.000 10    2020.10.26D00:00:00.000000000
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
update roundedDt:?[(`ss$dt)within(0;14);`time$(`int$`time$dt)-1000*`ss$dt;
    ?[(`ss$dt)within(15;44);`time$30000+(`int$`time$dt)-1000*`ss$dt;`time$60000+(`int$`time$dt)-1000*`ss$dt]] from t
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a modified version of `xbar` that rounds to nearest int instead of flooring:

```
q)xbar2:{type[y]$x*"j"$y%x:$[16h=abs type x;"j"$x;x]}
q)update roundedDt:xbar2[30;dt.second] from t
dt                      price roundedDt
---------------------------------------
2021.10.25T09:30:28.000 9.99  09:30:30
2021.10.25T09:30:32.000 10    09:30:30
```

Note that because this function is defined in root namespace you must use bracket notation (`xbar2[30;dt.second]`). If you wish to use infix notation (`30 xbar2 dt.second`), you'll need to define the function in `.q` namespace i.e. `.q.xbar2:{type[y]$x*"j"$y%x:$[16h=abs type x;"j"$x;x]}`.

`xbar2` is based on the original `xbar`, but where `xbar` uses `div` which has the effect of flooring the result, here `%` is used which will produce a float output and this is then cast to a long int which will round to the nearest integer.

Answer (score 1):

What about this solutions:

```
/ x is your timestamp
/ y is the timebucket (in seconds)
.time.round:{
    :"z"$+[`date$x;`time$1e3*y*`int$%[`time$x;y*1e3]];
 };
```

As example, if you want to round at the nearest 30 seconds, you need to use this as follows:

```
ts1:2020.10.30T10:32:35
.time.round[ts1;30]
```

In your case, simply type:

```
t[`round_time]:{.time.round[x;30]} each t[`dt]
```

As a side note, some of the proposed solutions would round timestamps like 2020.10.25T23:59:59 and 2020.10.26T00:00:01 to 24:00:00 and 00:00:00 respectively, which is not what we would like I suppose.

Comment: Valid point and perhaps I've missed what delita is trying to achieve. I will update my solution with a timestamp alternative.

Comment: @MattMoore I like your solution - it is very clean